# Error 404 Not found Error while using simple-json-replay-server

Tags: angular, http, post, mockserver

I am creating an angular application with a simple-json-replay-server as a mock server, I have the API POST call.

mock POST call

```json
{
    "request": {
        "path": "upload",
        "method":"post",
     },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "applicantDetail": [
                {
                  "appId": "2",
                  "firstName": "qqq",
                  "lastName": "rrr"
                },
                {
                  "appId": "1",
                  "firstName": "xyz",
                  "lastName": "s"
                }
              ]
        }
    }
}
```

my proxy settings

```json
{
    "proxy": {
        "/api": "http://localhost:8008"
    }
}
```

After running the npm run mockServer I am getting this error

[image]

when I am making the post call it throwing the following error.
[image]

Please help with this issue.

Comment: For the first screenshot - it can't work as browser is requesting GET, not POST.

Comment: Add `"logLevel": "debug"` to proxy, might help you get more info.

Comment: my api is for post, how it expecting get call, do i need to make any changes to act like post call. when i  changed post to get its working fine but i want this mock server for post call